# Two different colored fair dice are thrown. Check if two events are independent

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Two different colored fair dice are thrown. Let E1 be the event that the scores
differ by 3, and let E2 be the event that the sum of the scores is 5. Are the two events independent and why? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $36$ (equally likely) outcomes $\Omega=\{(1,1),\cdots,(6,6)\}$.

Now 
$$E_1=\{(1,4),(2,5),(3,6),(4,1),(5,2),(6,3)\}$$
 and
$$E_2=\{(1,4),(2,3),(4,1),(3,2)\}$$
So
$$E_1\cap E_2=\{(1,4),(4,1)\}$$
We see that
$$\mathbb{P}(E_1)=\frac{6}{36}=\frac{1}{6},\;\;\;\mathbb{P}(E_2)=\frac{4}{36}=\frac{1}{9},\;\;\;\mathbb{P}(E_1\cap E_2)=\frac{2}{36}=\frac{1}{18}$$
Hence
$$\mathbb{P}(E_1\cap E_2)=\frac{1}{18}\neq\frac{1}{54}=\mathbb{P}(E_1)*\mathbb{P}(E_2)$$
Therefore the two events are not independent.